# How to get external PHP variables in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

i'm making a Captcha for a form validate and I made this so far (I made it with a tutorial)

```
<?php
session_start();

function random($length){
    $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $str = "";
    $size = strlen($chars);
    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
        $str .= $chars[rand(0, $size-1)];
    }
    return $str;
}

$cap = random(6);
$_SESSION['real'] = $cap;

$image = imagecreate(70, 20);
$background = imagecolorallocate($image, 86, 178, 167);
$foreground = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

imagestring($image, 5,5,1,$cap,$foreground);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
?>
```

then wrote this code on my HTML:

```
<img src="image-captcha.php" alt="captcha">
```

**image-captcha.php** is the name of the external file with the PHP code above.
What I want to achieve is getting the PHP variable $cap from the HTML (in jQuery), something like:

```
$(function(){
  var captcha = '<? php echo $cap; ?>';
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that not working?

Comment: No you dont. If you do that then the user can view your page source and know what the string is. So therefore a robot can do the same. Result = Captcha not worth having

Comment: no, I used alert(captcha) and it showed '<? php echo $cap; ?>'

Comment: I'm speculating here, but if you're aiming at reproducing a client based response (page does not refresh) to the captcha entry, that's not how it's done. Lookup ajax requests.

Answer (score 3):

```
<? php echo $cap; ?>
```

should be

```
<?php echo $cap; ?>
```

Comment: But still **you dont want to do this** it makes a nonsence of having a Captcha!!!

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want the captcha in your javascript?
If you do so bots will be able to read your source code and bypass your captcha anyway.

To make this work with PHP, suppose you have a form using the POST method, you could use an if statement on the processing page like (no validation included)

```
if ($_POST['captcha'] == $_SESSION['real']) { .... }
```

Comment: so do you recommend me doing it with PHP?

Comment: Thats a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Yes, I would process the captcha by PHP since it is server-side and bots will not be able to read your captcha code.

Comment: Suppose you have a form using the POST method, you could use an if statement on the processing page like (no validation included) if ($_POST['captcha'] == $_SESSION['real']) { .... }

Comment: Please change your response below so I can mark it as correct answer!